# Anaconda returns error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: anaconda

I want to install Anaconda for programming AI. However, after the installation, it popped out the error: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified, and concluded that it could not run the post-install script.

I tried pressing ignore, and after turning on Anaconda Prompt, it responded quite the same as the WindowsError: The system cannot find the path specified.

I have been searching on Stackoverflow and found out a post, but no one has answered it. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend manually finding the Anaconda Prompt via the file explorer, as in manually go to Program Files or Program Files (x86) and click on the executable. I assume Windows may not have created the shortcut properly, or the application was moved to a different location than Windows was expecting it to be in.

If it still says that the system cannot find the file specified, I would uninstall it via the control panel. Afterwards, make sure to install the right version for your computer (either 32 or 64 bits).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have tried various versions, 32 and 64 bit, and also python 2.7 and python 3.7. Moreover, I don't see any Anaconda.exe in my installation folder.

Comment: @ShrikeDanny You are getting the 64 bit graphical installer from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ right? There are also other alternatives to installing the Anaconda distribution of python, like using CoCalc or Azure Notebooks. You could also try it out on there for free if you just want to try out Jupyter/IPython Notebooks. It may not be as fast as on your computer. Try using https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/ to verify that you aren't missing any steps